# Find conditions on the distribution on $X$, but what is meant by $X$?

Tags: markov-chains

> > Let $X, X_{n,k}$ for $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ denote independent random variables with values in $\mathbb{N}_0$. Define $N_0:=1$ and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ set
> >     $$
> > N_n:=\begin{cases}0, & \text{ if }N_{n-1}=0\\X_{n,1}+\cdots+X_{n,N_{n-1}}, & \text{ if }N_{n-1}>0.\end{cases}
> > $$
> >     Find conditions on the distribution of $X$ for which the probability
> >     $$
> > q:=P(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n=0)
> > $$
> >     satisfies $q=0$.

In a first step I showed that $(N_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ is a Markov chain, see here ([Check if $(N_n)$ is a Markov chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008911/check-if-n-n-is-a-markov-chain)).

Now I really wonder what is meant with $X$, what exactly is $X$? I did not understand this yet.

Maybe you can help me?

If I undestood what $X$ shall be, maybe I then can find the asked condition.

Because we recently had *generating functions* maybe it then has sth to do with that.

Comment: Are you sure the identity at the end is not $q=1$?

Comment: Yes, it is $q=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I really wonder what is meant with X, what exactly is X?

The random variable $X$ is any random variable distributed like $X_{1,1}$. It appears only through its distribution.

Comment: Which text are you following?

Comment: I only use my papers I wrote in the lecture.

Comment: Could you please explain to me, how one can read from the task that $X$ is distributed like $X_{1,1}$?

Comment: Is it possible that it is NOT POSSIBLE that $q=0$?

Comment: "Could you please explain to me, how one can read from the task that X is distributed like X1,1?" One cannot, the "task" is not very well written (but I know this setting, which is why I can add what is missing).

Comment: "Is it possible that it is NOT POSSIBLE that q=0?" No, in some cases one has q=0.

Comment: My idea is that $P(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n=0)=P(N_1=0)=P(X=0)=1-P(X>0)=1-g_X(1)$ where $g_X$ is the generating function. And it is $g_X(1)=P(X<\infty)=1$. But what is now the condition that is asked?

Comment: ?? But P(∃n∈ℕ:Nn=0) is not P(N1=0), is it?

Comment: You are right. Thats wrong. How to start then?

Comment: Is this your question? I thought your question was to understand X.

Comment: Yes, my original question was how to understand $X$. But now this new question arose. I wonder if I should use $q=1-P(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n>0)$ and to continue with that; whereat my question would be: how to do so.

Comment: New problem $\implies$ new question.

Comment: Ok, I will post a new thread for m new question! Thank you.