# Finding a condition for which it is $P(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n=0)=0$

Tags: markov-chains

> > Let $X, X_{n,k}$ for $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ denote independent random variables with values in $\mathbb{N}_0$. Define $N_0:=1$ and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ set
> >     $$
> > N_n:=\begin{cases}0, & \text{ if }N_{n-1}=0\\X_{n,1}+\cdots+X_{n,N_{n-1}}, & \text{ if }N_{n-1}>0.\end{cases}
> > $$
> >     Find conditions on the distribution of $X$ for which the probability
> >     $$
> > q:=P(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n=0)
> > $$
> >     satisfies $q=0$.

In this thread ( [Find conditions on the distribution on $X$, but what is meant by $X$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009000/find-conditions-on-the-distribution-on-x-but-what-is-meant-by-x/1009404?noredirect=1#comment2061877_1009404)) I learned that $X$ is any random variable that has the same Distribution as $X_{1,1}=N_1$.

Now my next question is, how to find the desired condition under which it is $q=0$.

---

I think one maybe can start with
$P(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n=0)=1-P(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n>0)$, but that's already the Point where I do not know how to continue.

**Edit**

Another possibility could be to start with 
$$
P(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n=0)=P(H(0)<\infty)
$$
whereat
$$
H(0)=\inf\left\{n\geq 1: N_n=0\right\}.
$$
But here I do not know how to continue as well. Maybe
$$
P_X(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n=0)=P_X(H(0)<\infty)=\sum_n P_X(H(0)=n)\\=\sum_n\sum_lP(H(0)=n,X=l)
$$

Comment: $$q=0\iff P(X=0)=0$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you get that?

Comment: By the way: I asked the questioner and he said that I can assume that the $X$ is identically distributed as all $X_{n,k}$.

Comment: "Could you please explain how you get that?" Surely you can prove one direction.

Comment: Ok, not very difficult, right. Now I would like to know a condition for $q=1$. But I think I have to ask this as a new question. :D

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010862/find-condition-on-x-so-that-p-exists-n-in-mathbbn-n-n-0-1

Answer (score 0):

Something is weird here... You can rewrite $q$ as follows

$$q=P(\bigcup_{n=1} \{N_n = 0\}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(N_n = 0)$$

Once the events $\{N_n = 0\}$ are increasing.

But, the sequence $P(N_n = 0)$ are increasing. So, if for some $n$ you have $P(N_n = 0)=\delta > 0$ then obviously $q \ge \delta$

So to start, $X$ can't be zero, I.e., $P(X_{11} = 0)=0$. But this isn't a sufficient, because $N_2$ could be zero with positive probability if the $X_{2j}$ have some chance to assume zero too. So is necessary that all $X$'s don't assume the value zero with positive probability.

Comment: "This" (that P(X=0)=0) is quite sufficient.

Comment: Really? Well, I believe I didn't understand the question. If $X$ is just the distribution of $X_11$ and you allow $X_21$, for example, has another distribution which gives positive probability to zero, then $P(N_2 = 0) > 0$ hence $q>0$... What am I missing?

Comment: That the question is horribly formulated and that one should understand that $X$ and every $X_{n,k}$ are i.i.d. Not yor fault.