# Find condition on $X$ so that $P(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n=0)=1$

Tags: markov-chains

> > Let $X, X_{n,k}$ for $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ denote independent random variables with values in $\mathbb{N}_0$. $X$ is identically distributed as all $X_{n,k}$. Define $N_0:=1$ and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ set
> >     $$
> > N_n:=\begin{cases}0, & \text{ if }N_{n-1}=0\\X_{n,1}+\cdots+X_{n,N_{n-1}}, & \text{ if }N_{n-1}>0.\end{cases}
> > $$
> >     Find conditions on the distribution of $X$ for which the probability
> >     $$
> > q:=P(\exists n\in\mathbb{N}: N_n=0)
> > $$
> >     satisfies $q=1$.

Defining the hitting time of $0$ as $H(0)=\inf\left\{n\geq 0: N_n=0\right\}$, it is
$$
q=P(H(0)<\infty).
$$

Now the only idea I have is to start like this:
$$
P(H(0)<\infty)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}P(H(0)=n)\\
=\sum_n P(N_n=0|N_{n-1}>0,...,N_0=1)
$$
Markov property:
$$
=\sum_n P(N_n=0|N_{n-1}>0)\\
=\sum_{n}\frac{P(N_n=0,N_{n-1}>0)}{P(N_{n-1}>0)}\\
=\sum_n \frac{P(X_{n,1}+\cdots+X_{n,N_{n-1}}=0)}{P(X_{n-1,1}+\cdots+N_{n-1,N_{n-2}}>0)}
$$

X identically distributed as all $X_{n,k}$:

$$
=\sum_{n}\frac{P(N_{n-1}\cdot X=0)}{P(N_{n-2}\cdot X>0)}
$$

In case that this makes any sense: How do I have to continue?
Give me some help, please.

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition is that $E(X)\leqslant1$ (and that $P(X=1)\ne1$ if $E(X)=1$). This is basic theory of [Galton-Watson processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process#Extinction_criterion_for_Galton.E2.80.93Watson_process).

Comment: I really wonder why this is on worksheet, because we did not have that. -- So my idea is absolute useless?

Comment: Are you able to use generating functions?

Comment: If you mean if we had that in the lecture: yes. We defined what a generating function is and had some Basic properties; for a random variable $X$ with values in $\mathbb{N}_0\Cup\left\{\infty\right\}$ we had $g_X(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}P(X=n)z^n, z\in\mathbb{C}$ as the generating function. Moreover we had that $g_X(1)=P(X<\infty)$.

Comment: More importantly, $P(N_n=0)=g_{N_n}(0)$. What can you say about $g_{N_n}$?

Comment: I had a look in my lecture. I list all things that I found that I can say about $g_{N_n}$, namely, (1.) it is non-negative, monotonically increasing and continuous (2.) it is convex (3.) $g_{N_n}(z)=E(z^{N_n}|N_n<\infty)P(N_n<\infty)$.

Comment: Does any of this help me to continue? (3.) says that $g_{N_n}(z)=E(z^{N_n}|N_n<\infty)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}_0}E(z^{N_n}|N_n=m)\cdot 1_{\left\{N_n=m\right\}}$.